# Position: absolute; inside dynamic position: relative; element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

This is an IE7 bug:

I have a piece of a table that I push to another `<tbody>`. Ok, the problem is that inside the cells I have a position: relative; div and inside this div I have several other `position:absolute;` divs.

The thing is that they are being rendered as if the parent div wasn't position:relative, that means, completely at the top left corner of the screen. WHY?!?!

In ff,chrome it works fine, but at IE7 I get these annoying things. I've tried putting hasLayout everywhere but it just doesn't work.

Here is what I have:

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody id="mtbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is what I receive and push to "mtbody" (sample):

```
<table id="testando">
<tr>
        <td hasLayout="true" class="uhr sl" colspan="7" style="border-bottom: dashed 1px #dddddd; background-color: #eeffee;">
            <div style="overflow: hidden;" class="holdU" hasLayout="true" betriebsId="83113" betriebsName="2nd Level">
                <div hasLayout="true" class="uhr filled0sl" style="width: 679px; left: 0px;">
                </div>


                    <div hasLayout="true" class="border" style="left: 96">
....
```

So class "holdU" is position:relative, and the classes "uhr" are position: absolute, and they are right now in my top left corner, sort of invisible.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

So basically this is the expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/kgT6E/ (from DanielB). But I'm NOT getting that. Imagine that this green square is now 100px away from the borders but instead of wrapping the red squares, they are staying at the top left corner, as the position: relative from the green square is not making any effect.

This is the code that I use to load the things to the table:

```
$.get(savedUrl, function(res) {
        var div = $("<div>").html(res);
// this is because I get other stuff together, but what I really want is the tbody content.
        $("#mtbody").html($(div.find("tbody").get(0)).html());
});
```

Before, I was loading everything to the tbody,
    $("#mtbody").load(savedUrl)

But the IE7 wasn't recognizing the TR's and TD's, so I had to wrap them in a table. Now I'm getting this odd positioning from the position:absolute divs.

UPDATE2: I have tried putting all the units (23 **px** ) but no luck so far. I think it's because I have to first wrap it in a div, and when I do so, the positions don't get updated.. really strange and nasty bug from IE.. =/

Comment: Can you come up with a simple example that demonstrates this behavior on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging a bit I've found a very nasty "float: left" in div.uhr style.
Basically that was breaking all the layout in IE7 making the div's with "position:absolute" appear out of the screen.

So people, take care about it! ;D

Answer (score 2):

This is not an IE7 bug. If your HTML and CSS is valid, it works.

Have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kgT6E/).

Also, you should not put a `<table>` into a `<tbody>`. `<tbody>` should have `<tr>` children only.

## edit

Also your inline style definition is missing a unit of measurement.

```
<div hasLayout="true" class="border" style="left: 96">
```

should be

```
<div hasLayout="true" class="border" style="left: 96px">
```

Comment: May be you can post your complete resulting HTML in a fiddle.

Comment: But in your style sheet `div.uhr` has `position: relative` not absolute.

Comment: yeap, but filled1 and filled1sl add those properties.. =/

Comment: Okay sorry, but the code you've posted is not well formatted for readability. As you see in my example, it will work in IE7. You should simplify your code step by step an see at which point it breaks. Do you have a doctype definition on your page?

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm working on it. The thing is that I'm really frustrated, since I have this ton of stuff done working in chrome and firefox, and now IE is getting in my way. Anyway, I will try to strip it part by part. Thanks! ;D

Comment: So I've found the problem.. read answer ;D Thx for everything

Comment: Na dann Gückwunsch! (thought could throw some German, because your code includes lot of German phrases) ;-)